# Making a bot that sends a message that you can react to and gives a role. Discord Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to code a bot that sends a message with a reactable icon which you can click on it will give you a role, but if you un react if removes the role.

This is what I had, but it isn't practical.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'bumper_role':
        role = get(message.server.roles, name='bumper_role')
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `role = get(message.server.roles, name='bumper_role')`
with  `role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='bumper_role')`.

Also replace `await client.add_roles(message.author, role)` with `await message.author.add_roles(role)`

Have a nice day :)